# Get twitter profile picture with Parse - Android

Tags: android, twitter, parse-platform

I am stuck on trying to get a Twitter ParseUser's profile picture. I have used ParseTwitterUtils to allow the user to log in to my app, and am attempting to get their profile picture upon sign up to my parse database.

I have used the following from Parse docs:

```html
ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
    if (user == null) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
    } else if (user.isNew()) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!"); 
          ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().getUserId();
    user.setUsername(ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter()
                .getScreenName());
              
    user.saveInBackground();
    makeTwitterRequest();
    MyActivity();
    } else {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
    }
  }
});
```

The logging in works absolutely fine, and it gets the user name fine. Here is my makeTwitterRequest() method to attempt to get the profile picture so far. I havn't yet attempted to store it to Parse, only to get it using a Twitter API call:

```html
private void makeTwitterRequest() {
     

     Twitter twitter = ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter();
     String twitterUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=" + twitter.getUserId();
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet request = new HttpGet(twitterUrl);
     twitter.signRequest(request);
  try {
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
   
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

Upon running this, whenever I hit the Twitter login button and log in, upon authenticating, I receive an error:

```html
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055): Leak found
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055): java.lang.IllegalStateException: AndroidHttpClient created and never closed
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.<init>(AndroidHttpClient.java:158)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(AndroidHttpClient.java:144)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at com.parse.twitter.Twitter.authorize(Twitter.java:115)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at com.parse.TwitterAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(TwitterAuthenticationProvider.java:39)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at com.parse.ParseUser.authenticateAsync(ParseUser.java:1482)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at com.parse.ParseUser.logInWithAsync(ParseUser.java:1502)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at com.parse.ParseUser.logInWithAsync(ParseUser.java:1291)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at com.parse.ParseTwitterUtils.logInInBackground(ParseTwitterUtils.java:247)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at com.parse.ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(ParseTwitterUtils.java:264)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at <mypackagename>.SignUpOrLoginActivity.onTwitterLoginButtonClicked(SignUpOrLoginActivity.java:231)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at <mypackagename>.SignUpOrLoginActivity.access$2(SignUpOrLoginActivity.java:229)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at <mypackagename>.SignUpOrLoginActivity$5.onClick(SignUpOrLoginActivity.java:95)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-05 19:06:56.076: E/AndroidHttpClient(15055):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I believe that Parse is supposed to sort this out automatically with the log in procedure, however does anybody know what is wrong? Thanks very much for your time!

Answer (score 3):

You can use following snippet of code:

```
Twitter twitter = ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter();

HttpGet verifyGet = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=" + twitter.getUserId());
ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().signRequest(verifyGet);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = null;

try {
    request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(verifyGet.getURI().toURL())
            .addHeader("Authorization", verifyGet.getFirstHeader("Authorization").getValue())
            .build();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            String jsonString = response.body().string();
        }
    }
});
```

It depends on OkHttp by Square (https://github.com/square/okhttp)